# Connecting Objects with two View controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my project I have two view controllers, and I am having trouble connecting objects such as an UIImageView to the view controller. When I try to create the IBOutlet, it tells me that "Could not insert new outlet collection: could not find any information for the class named UIViewController". I believe this problem stems from the fact that my original declaration of my class is as follows:

```
    class UIViewController: UIViewController {
```

when in fact the view controller is named mainScene instead. However, when I change the first UIViewController to what I think it should be (mainScene), it doesn't even show me the option of connecting an IBOutlet...

```
    class mainScene: UIViewController {
```

So, I have two questions.

1. Do I need to have a whole separate class for the second UIViewController and would that solve my issues?
2. Is there a better way to link objects to the UIViewController or am I just doing something horribly wrong (the likely scenario)?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: 1.  Yes, and yes.  2.  There's no better way, and you're not doing something horribly wrong.  (You probably just missed a step.)

You have two view controllers.  Assuming they are different, you would subclass each one from `UIViewController` with a different name.  E.g., mainSceneViewController and otherSceneViewController.

Your mainSceneViewController and otherSceneViewController would each have their own properties and IBOutlets.

Where you're probably stuck, is needing to change the class of your viewController within Interface Builder to match the class name in its .swift file, so IB knows what outlets it can connect for that view controller.

Each scene in your storyboard corresponds to a view controller.  When the segue is performed, iOS instantiates your view controller from the storyboard.

While it is possible to only have one view controller subclass, and use the same subclass for different views, it doesn't happen too often.

**Update:**

Subclassing lets you add properties and methods to a class, and override their superclass.

In your comment, `UIViewController` is the class, and `mainSceneViewController` is subclassed from `UIViewController`.  For your second view controller, it would likely be `class otherSceneViewController: UIViewController {`, as your other scene would likely require a different properties and methods from your main scene view controller.

You can [read more about Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) in the Swift Programming Language guide.

Comment: How exactly would I subclass this like you mentioned? Should I use two different .swift files, and then start each with class mainSceneViewController: UIVIewController {

Comment: Yes, you'd have two different .swift files, each with a different "scene" name. For example GameOverViewController.swift would start with `class GameOverViewController: UIViewController {`.